# Playing an animation while data is loading

Tags: ios, objective-c

Currently in my `AppDelegate.m` I have the code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    CGRect  rect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    UIImageView *imageView =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
    imageView.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"Comp 2_00000.png"],..., nil];
    imageView.animationDuration = 6;
    imageView.animationRepeatCount = 1;
    [imageView startAnimating];
    [self.window addSubview:imageView];

    return YES;
}
```

Which plays an animation I have once my view did load code in my ViewController.m has loaded some data which takes around 5 seconds.

I load the data like this using JSON and URLS:

```
 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://xxxxxxxx.co.uk/untitled%20folder/jsonimages.php"];
    NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    NSError *error = nil;

    NSDictionary *result = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData
                                                           options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
```

Is there anyway for the animation to play while the data is loading?

Comment: why not edit your question to show how you are loading your data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a helper function (make it static if you need to reuse it):

**Function:**

```
-(UIImageView *) InitImageView{    
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    CGRect  rect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    UIImageView *imageView =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
    imageView.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                           [UIImage imageNamed:@"Comp 2_00000.png"],..., nil];
    //imageView.animationDuration = 6;
    imageView.animationRepeatCount = 1;

    [self.view addSubview:imageView];

    return imageView;
}
```

**Ansynchronous Task:**

```
//Start Animation
UIImageView *imageView = [self InitImageView];
[imageView startAnimating];

dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("co.uk.bits.bots", NULL);
dispatch_async(queue, ^{
 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://xx.co.uk/jsonimages.php"];
    NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    NSError *error = nil;

    NSDictionary *result = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData
                         options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        //Stop Animation
        [imageView stopAnimating];
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is to dispatch the data request and then call the animation:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://xxxxxxxx.co.uk/untitled%20folder/jsonimages.php"];
    NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    NSError *error = nil;

    NSDictionary *result = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
              //Main thread stuff, after loading the data
              [self animate];
        });
});
```

....

```
- (void)animate {
    CGRect  rect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    UIImageView *imageView =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
    imageView.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"Comp 2_00000.png"],..., nil];
    imageView.animationDuration = 6;
    imageView.animationRepeatCount = 1;
    [imageView startAnimating];
    [self.view addSubview:imageView];
}
```

Comment: Is that in the ViewController.m?

Comment: Yes thats in your ViewController, what this is going to do is download the data in a separate thread, leaving the main thread free to do your animation ;)

Comment: `[self.window addSubview:imageView];` is giving an error

Comment: Should it be `[self addSubview:imageView];`

Comment: I fixed the code, it should be `[self.view addSubView]`

Answer (score 0):

This code may get your app rejected from the app store because it will force the user to wait for six seconds on every app launch.  the Apple guidelines say that app launches should happen as fast as possible.

Could you refactor it so that your initial view controller can be displayed without the data at first, then update it incrementally as the data becomes available?

If the data is loaded from the network you could also cache it so that subsequent launches are faster.

Comment: Is this true? Because I have seen a few apps like the network [EE](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/my-ee/id567457151?mt=8)'s app have a start up animation. It just consequently makes the startup time about 10 seconds. And I thought that I might as well hide this waiting at the beginning with an animation. And even when I cache the images to have this animation. Just because it is nice.

Comment: There is no problem in having an animation on startup while your data loads, but you have to do it outside the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method. The `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method must return fast or you can get rejected : but you can, in the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`, present a controller that will display your loading and give the focus to the app as quickly as possible.